# transform input json in two different collections shares same property from input json

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

## Sample input JSON

```json
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "lastName": "PQR",
  "address": "abc, mnop, 534291"
}
```

## Expected output JSON with shared properties

```json
{
  "employee": {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "lastName": "PQR",
    "address": "abc, mnop, 534291"
  },

  "address": {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "lastName": "PQR",
    "address": "abc, mnop, 534291"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`*`** and **`@`** wildcards together within a **shift** transformation like this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "address.&", // this needs an ampersand to replicate the whole content
      "@": "employee"   // while this one doesn't
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

or another alternative option might be :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": ["employee", "address"]
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** is :

[image]